# Why is the blue box (div) not placed at the top of the page even though it is not relative to any parent and it is set to position absolute?

Tags: html, css

If I am not wrong, adding a `position: absolute;` to your element will remove it from normal document flow, and if there is no relative parent it will be relative to the HTML element (the page itself).

So if that's the case, the blue box (`.box::before`) will be placed at the top left of the page, no? Since it's not relative to any parent, and I have also set `top: 0; and left: 0;`.

So why is the blue box still in the center?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #233637;
}

.card{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid #eee;
    border-right: 170px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 170px solid #ccc;
}

.box{
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: #ff3838;
}

.box::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

[This is the image example of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSF6y.png)

Comment: It is because of your transform on the .box. If you were able to remove that it would work as you are expecting. You could always just make the .box positioned absolutely.

Comment: As well as `position` and `transform`, the properties `will-change` and `contain` can also cause a box to establish an absolute positioning containing block

Comment: @jons Ah yes this is what i'm expecting, but i don't quite fully understand why removing transform will give the result that i'm expecting. Could you elaborate it more?

Comment: @Alohci Sorry i don't quite understand what you meant by absolute positioning containing block. Would you be able to elaborate it more?

Comment: @Max - First, the "no relative parent" CSS2 rule that you mention, is actually "no positioned ancestor". i.e. a `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` ancestor would be as effective as `position:relative`. Second, this notion of "positioned ancestor"  has been generalised in CSS3 to an element that "establishes an absolute positioning containing block", so that other ancestors beyond those that are positioned can also have the same effect. One of those is `transform`, when it has any value other than it's default value of `none`.

Comment: I meant such as those elements with the`transform` property, when it has any value other than its default value of none This is less surprising than it might seem. To modern browsers, `position:relative` is implemented as a translate transform, so the rules that apply to `position:relative` kind of have to apply to transform too.

Comment: @Max think of the transform like position relative in a way. Since it is moving things around, etc. And because of that, the child with position: absolute; is relative to that.

Comment: @jons I get it now, thank you again

Comment: @Alohci i get it now, Thanks for pointing out my mistake